# Find and replace that can find a string that has an unknown number

Tags: c#, xml, replace, numbers

I have a txt file like this where the ID can vary:

```
<Hmi.Screen.Property Name="FitToLargest" AggregationName="Properties" ID="67">          
   <AttributeList>
      <Value>false</Value>
   </AttributeList>
</Hmi.Screen.Property>
```

I wrote a program in C# that loads a XML file and can find and replace text.
This is the find and replace code i already have:

```
private void btnFindReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(tbLoad.Text, File.ReadAllText(tbLoad.Text).Replace(tbFind.Text, tbReplace.Text));

            messageSucces();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageCancel();
        }
    }
```

What can I do to find this XML code and replace without looking at the ID, because the piece of code that I need to delete appears multiple times throughout the file but with a different ID number every time. I need to delete them all.

Comment: Load it into a string and do `.Replace("code to replace..", "");` ? Have you tried running the code you already have?

Comment: What I have works, but because of the ID I can't find it. The ID is different every time.

Comment: What exactly are you passing in for the replace part?

Comment: I have a XML file with 2,000,000 lines. This code is just a part of the whole document. I want to delete this part because it is in the code around 400 times but with differt ID numbers. I want to delete all that 400 parts of code, not replacing it sorry.

Comment: Do each of these nodes have the same `Name` attribute?

Comment: yes, the name attribute is always FitToLargest

Comment: Cool, then I have an answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the elements you want to remove from your XML are the **only ones** with the attribute/value `Name="FitToLargest"` then you could use a LINQ to XML query to get those elements by attribute name and then remove them.

For example:

```
//this will be a path to your XML file or a string containing the XML
//I've used 'tbLoad.Text' as I don't know where you're getting the XML from
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(tbLoad.Text);

xml.Descendants().Elements("Hmi.Screen.Property")
                 .Where(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "FitToLargest").Remove();
xml.Save("file path here...");
```

This will remove all `Hmi.Screen.Property` elements that have `FitToLargest` as their `Name` attribute.

Comment: Sure, it can go anywhere.

Comment: Do i have to make new variables or Using system?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking? You might need to add some new `Using` statements to include the `XDocument` class if that's what you mean?

Comment: HttpContext does not exist in the current context. I added the using system.Web, what do I do?

Comment: `HttpContext`? You shouldn't need that at all here?

Comment: Oh sorry I might have copied it, I was working on different projects at the same time.